# Converting a UserResponse with ToDate returning only January in Business Objects

Tags: business-objects

I am trying to convert a User Response from a report's prompt into a date. The `ToDate()` and `FormatDate()` functions work correctly, but only return the month of January.

I created a detail object called `[xUser Response]` whose formula is:

`=UserResponse([Hours]; "As of Period YYYYMM")`,

where `[Hours]` is the data source and "As of Period YYYYMM" is the prompt string.

Then, I used this detail object in another formula:

```
="Data as of "+ FormatDate(LastDayOfMonth(ToDate([xUser Response]; "yyyymm")); "Mmmm dd, yyyy")
```

The formatting applied through the other functions is all correct, but the date only gives me January, no matter what month I submit in the query prompt. If you know how to get around this, please let me know.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `yyyyMM` as a format mask to convert your string to a date. `mm` is used to denote minutes.

Thus, your formula would be `="Data as of "+ FormatDate(LastDayOfMonth(ToDate([xUser Response]; "yyyyMM")); "Mmmm dd, yyyy")`